# why can't i await readasarray method in gdal module?

Tags: python, numpy, gdal, python-asyncio

I am trying to read several remote images into python and read those image as numpyarray, I try to consider using async to boost my workflow, but I get an error like this:type error: object numpy.ndarray can't be used in 'await' expression',I wonder is it because the method readasarray is not async, so if I have to make it async, I will have to rewrite this method by my own.here are some of my code:

```
async def taskIO_1():

    in_ds = gdal.Open(a[0])
    data1 = await in_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

async def taskIO_2():

    in_ds = gdal.Open(a[1])
    data2 = await in_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

async def main():

    tasks = [taskIO_1(), taskIO_2()]
    done,pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    for r in done:
        print(r.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
    print(float(time.time()-start))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notion is correct: In general, library functions are executed in a synchronized (blocking) fashion, unless the library is explicitly written to support asynchronous execution (e.g. by using non-blocking I/O), such as [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) or [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

To use synchronous calls that you want to be executed asynchronously, you could use `loop.run_in_executor`. This does nothing else than to offload the computation into a separate thread or process and wrap it so it behaves like a coroutine. An example is shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

def blocking_io():
    # File operations (such as logging) can block the
    # event loop: run them in a thread pool.
    with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read(100)

def cpu_bound():
    # CPU-bound operations will block the event loop:
    # in general it is preferable to run them in a
    # process pool.
    return sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    ## Options:

    # 1. Run in the default loop's executor:
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(
        None, blocking_io)
    print('default thread pool', result)

    # 2. Run in a custom thread pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, blocking_io)
        print('custom thread pool', result)

    # 3. Run in a custom process pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, cpu_bound)
        print('custom process pool', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

However, if your application is not using any truly asynchronous features, you are probably better off to just use `concurrent.futures` pool directly and achieve concurrency that way.

Comment: thanks for your answer,this    loop.run_in_executor    open a new thread,but as far as I know,there is no true multithread in python, compare to asyncio, is multithreading more effective?are those thread completely separated and will never affect each other?

Comment: It depends. If I/O is the bottleneck, then threads tend to work well in practice (but have higher overhead than coroutines). If it's computationally bound, you can use processes instead of threads (see example 3). If your rasters are reasonably big, threads and processes are perfectly fine to use, but you have to benchmark it.

Comment: I think my issue is mainly about I/O, turning raster into numpy-array and write array into disk is the main block,that is why i tied to use coroutine

Comment: I tired to used your code to create two thread to run two I/O task, but the time it cost were same as synchronous blocking way，I don't know which part is wrong; Then I tired to use a different peocess, but it cost even more time compare to synchronous way,why is that